# GL-A1300 DDNS Test Failing - Port Forwarding activated on ISP Router

Tags: vpn, wireguard, ddns

I purchased 2 Slate Plus. One to use as my Wireguard Server (connected to my ISP router at home) and the other one for travelling purposes as my Wireguard Client to ensure I always use my home ISP public IP address.

I did setup my Wireguard Server as well as the Client routers with the dynamic DNS configs and enabled dynamic DNS, I did also forward the standard suggested DDNS port from the admin panel on my ISP router both for UDP as well as TCP. So far so good.
**But somehow I still get the following error message when doing the DDNS test:**

> *“The IP from DDNS domain resolution is not the same as the WAN IPs of the device. You need an Internet Public IP address to use the Dynamic DNS. If this router is behind NAT, you may need to set up port forward in your ISP router. If you have VPN Client enabled, please disabled “Services from GL.iNet Use VPN” in the global options.”*

When I try following command:

> nslookup myDNS.glddns.com ddns.glddns.com

I am getting a request timed out.

Can anyone help me solve this?

[image: Screenshot of DDNS Test Interface]

**TLDR:** Enabled Port Forwarding on ISP Router, DDNS somehow not resolving. No carrier-NATing based on google research.

Comment: I just took a screenshot from the DDNS interface on my GL.iNet. 
Does the Interface WAN IP really have to be equal to my public IP in order for this to work?

Comment: Why do you have an ISP router acting as a router? In general, dual-NAT will cause all kinds of issues, especially if you're trying to access a service behind two NATs.

Comment: Because I am not sure if Wireguard works on my ISP Router

Comment: It probably doesn't. But in that case consider either taking out the ISP router altogether (and using your router as the only router), or (in case it's a modem/router combo unit so you need it) put the ISP device in to Bridge Mode to have it not do routing at all